# Зачем для style.left нужен парсинг

Tags: javascript, парсер

> imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 5 + 'px'; - код
>   работает
>
> imgObj.style.left = imgObj.style.left + 5 + 'px';  - код не работает

При этом для, например, height парсинг не нужен.

В чем в данном случае особенность для style.left, логически выходит, что он "считывается" из "пространства" в виде (string, radix)

Можете пояснить физику процесса?

Comment: свойство `left` содержит не число. Точнее оно содержит и число и символы `5px` одновременно, а операции можно делать только с числом без символов `5`. Ну если взять `'5px' + 5 + 'px'` => `5px5px`, а если `parseInt('5px') + 5 + 'px'` то будет верный результат

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Свойство `style.left` содержит не число а строку в формате число + единица измерения, например `"5px"`, если её спарсить

```
parseInt(obj.style.left)
```

то она превращается в число по правилам работы функции `parseInt`, берётся число в начале, остальное откидывается.

Если сделать код без функции `parseInt`, то что мы получим.

```
obj.style.left + 10 + "px"  = "5px10px"
```

Не валидная запись.

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо, уточню, чтоб не было белых пятен - а height содержит число (работает без парсинга)?

Comment: Почему height содержит число, height так же содержит строку, вот тестовый код - https://jsfiddle.net/Lcvkv8oz/1/

Comment: @Наташа если `height` брать из атрибута html то тогда там лежит то что в атрибуте, например `<img height="20"...`. Приведите код про который вы имеете виду про `height`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/uzvo1m6w/5/ Но height без парсинга работает только с подключением jquery. Получается height как "голое" число - это свойство jq

Comment: @Наташа видимо в jQuery height парсится уже внутри

Comment: @Наташа, у тебя перепутались [**свойство** `height` объекта `img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) и свойство [`height` у стиля](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Первый, как и указано - число. Второй, как и все свойства в `style` - строка.

Comment: @Grundy большое спасибо